# CRM2015: Validate a field on the first time a form is updated

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I've added a custom button on the form of some custom entity, that when clicked duplicates the record and opens the newly created record on a new window, i.e., the `FormType` of the newly created record is `update`.

On that opened window, I need to know whether the save button was clicked. As long it's not been clicked, some fields shall be open for edit; Once it was clicked, those fields shall be disabled.

Currently, I have a (hidden) bit field that indicates whether the record is a duplicate, and its initial value is set to true. On the first click of the save button, in my `onSave` function, I set it to false. In addition, I have an `onLoad` function checking this field for true (may happen only once a record was duplicated) or false.

My problem is a logical one: In order to set this field to false on the first save click, I actually need to do a validation every time the `save` button is clicked (and on non-duplicated records, too).

I thought maybe someone can offer some other, more logically-correct way, for doing the validation on a save event only once.

Here is the relevant snippet:

```
function OnLoad()
{
    // some code...
    if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("sln_isduplicate").getValue() == true)
    {
        // open for edit relevant fields
    }
    else
    {
       // close for edit relevant fields
    }
    // some code...
}

function OnSave()
{
    // some code...
    if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("sln_isduplicate").getValue() == true)
    {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("sln_isduplicate").setValue(false);
    }
    // some code...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call this:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("sln_isduplicate").setValue(false);
```

in your OnLoad function, after you did all the form modifications, so:

```
function OnLoad()
{
    // some code...
    if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("sln_isduplicate").getValue() == true)
    {
        // open for edit relevant fields
    }
    else
    {
       // close for edit relevant fields
    }

    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("sln_isduplicate").setValue(false);
}
```

It does not matter if it's a duplicate or not - you want user to set this flag to false when he saves the record.

The other approach would be to dynamically add onsave event (because I assume that you've added it on the form level). Basically it would look like this:

```
if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("sln_isduplicate").getValue() == true)
{
    // open for edit relevant fields
    Xrm.Page.data.entity.addOnSave(OnSave);
}
else
{
   // close for edit relevant fields
}
```

This approach would add your OnSave function only for record which are duplicates.

But on the other hand, I would not use a custom field for that, rather pass some query string parameter to indicate that this is a duplicate. You are probably opening your newly created record like that:

```
Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("entityname","A85C0252-DF8B-E111-997C-00155D8A8410");
```

But when you check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602956(v=crm.7).aspx#Anchor_3) for this function, you will see that it has more useful options for you:

```
 Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm(name,id,parameters,windowOptions)
```

where parameters can be default field ids or some completely custom values (but you have to [configure that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334436(v=crm.7).aspx))

So of course the obvious solution would be: open your duplicate record with some custom query string parameter, in onload function check for that parameter and if it's there, simply do your specific logic

Comment: Solutions 2 & 3 are exactly what I was looking for, thank you!